# Pandas dataframe split by memory usage

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to split up a pandas dataframe into multiple dataframes constrained by memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def split_dataframe(df, size):

    # size of each row
    row_size = df.memory_usage().sum() / len(df)

    # maximum number of rows of each segment
    row_limit = size // row_size

    # number of segments
    seg_num = (len(df) + row_limit - 1) // row_limit

    # split df
    segments = [df.iloc[i*row_limit : (i+1)*row_limit] for i in range(seg_num)]

    return segments
```

Comment: In my case, df shape is (338,11) but when I am passing size 10 in the function it gives me division zero error. Please help.

Comment: Can you put in an example please?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is if the columns of the dataframe are consistent datatypes (i.e., not objects). Here's an example of how you might go about this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from __future__ import division

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]*100, 'b': [1.1, 2] * 50, 'c': range(100)})

# calculate the number of bytes a row occupies
row_bytes = df.dtypes.apply(lambda x: x.itemsize).sum()

mem_limit = 1024

# get the maximum number of rows in a segment
max_rows = mem_limit / row_bytes

# get the number of dataframes after splitting
n_dfs = np.ceil(df.shape[0] / max_rows)

# get the indices of the dataframe segments
df_segments = np.array_split(df.index, n_dfs)

# create a list of dataframes that are below mem_limit
split_dfs = [df.loc[seg, :] for seg in df_segments]

split_dfs
```

Also, if you can split by columns instead of rows, pandas has a handy [`memory_usage`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.memory_usage.html) method.